# Find out the last updated record in my DB using MAX in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID primary key field on my table.

In order to find out the last updated record in my DB and the MAX(APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID) is presumed to be the most recent record.

I tried this code :

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN MAX(d.ApplicationStatusLog_ID) = d.ApplicationStatusLog_ID THEN d.ApplicationStatusID END) AS StatusID, 
FROM
    ApplicationStatusLog d
```

But I get error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 53 Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

My table looks like
ApplicationID - ApplicationStatusID - ApplicationStatusLogID
10000           17                    100
10000           08                    101
10000           10                    102
10001           06                    103
10001           10                    104
10002           06                    105
10002           07                    106

My output should be:
10000 10
10001 10
10002 07
Please help me understand and resolve my problem.

Comment: Probably going to need to see the full query.

Comment: I guess the error says it clearly no? You can not perform aggregate on an aggregate in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just find the last updated row, given that it has max value in APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID column. The query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM ApplicationStatusLog 
WHERE ApplicationStatusLog_ID = (SELECT MAX(ApplicationStatusLog_ID) FROM ApplicationStatusLog )
```

**EDIT**

So as you stated in comment, the query for it will be:

```
DECLARE @statusId INT
SELECT @statusId = STATUSID
FROM ApplicationStatusLog 
WHERE ApplicationStatusLog_ID = (SELECT MAX(ApplicationStatusLog_ID) FROM ApplicationStatusLog )
```

**EDIT 2:**

The query as per your edit in question will be:

```
 WITH C AS
(
    SELECT ApplicationID,ApplicationStatusID,ApplicationStatusLogID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ApplicationID ORDER BY ApplicationStatusLogID DESC) AS ranking
    FROM ApplicationStatusLog
)
SELECT ApplicationID,ApplicationStatusID
FROM C
WHERE ranking = 1
```

Comment: how can I have 'd.APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID = (SELECT MAX(APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID) FROM STG_TFS_NO.dbo.Origo_1_1_ApplicationStatusLog)'

Comment: How does this table 'STG_TFS_NO.dbo.Origo_1_1_ApplicationStatusLog' comes in picture. I have kept the table name same in both FROM clause so that it can give the last updated row.

Comment: The only thing I need is: to set the output of the SELECT statement in a variable in my query. I need to get the STATUSID of the most recent record that can be identifiedb by (MAX( APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID))

Comment: thanks! But still I get a problem! it updates the StatusID to the max and set it to all records. If I have another indicator, it wouldn't work.

Comment: When I put yours on my query all StatusIDs wil be set as 10

Comment: I found out what to do, just needed some small adjustments :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can join same table twice like this:

```
select IT.JoiningID, JT.MAXAPPLICATIONSTATUSID FROM dbo.[Table] IT 
    INNER JOIN (
        Select JoiningID, MAX (APPLICATIONSTATUSID) MAXAPPLICATIONSTATUSID
            FROM dbo.[Table] 
            GROUP BY JoiningID
    ) JT ON IT.JoiningID = JT.JoiningID
```

Now you have MAXAPPLICATIONSTATUSID per ID so you can write what you wand based on MAXAPPLICATIONSTATUSID.

Answer (score 0):

Without full query

```
SELECT 
 x.StatusId
 ...
FROM  <Table> a
CROSS APPLY
(
 SELECT x.APPLICATIONSTATUSID as StatusId
 FROM  <Table> x
 HAVING MAX(APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID) = a.APPLICATIONSTATUSLOG_ID
 GROUP BY x.APPLICATIONSTATUSID
)
```